# Send a list of URL's to a form a receive data on each one in a list

Tags: php, forms

I have a php code i wrote that takes a given url from a web form("`$website = $_POST['url'];`"), the code sends this url to an api i'm working with, and from there i'm getting back some information about the site(the api brings back xml). I'm checking the info and echo the information I want.

The form:

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="post">
url
<input type="text" name ="url" value=""><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

What I want to do, is to send to this code a list of URL's(few hundreds, for now) and get back a list of the data i previously echoed. So the code should be able to receive a big amount of data, treat each one separately, but then print all the data for all the URL's.
Looking for ideas on how to do that in the most correct and efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Well you would need to loop through the lets say 100 urls you would get.
You would need to send the urls at once as an array of urls, i would advise you to use a json encoded array for example.

This is how you could process it in your api.

```
$urls = $_POST['urls']; // if it a json encoded string then decode it with json_decode()
foreach($urls as $url) {
    //do something with $url
    //send it to the api and whatever
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. How can I receive the array using the form? I have a big, unknown and changing amount urls.

Comment: well it depends how you have your form, i see you have one input field, if i understand, than the urls will be added to that one input field or how would you like to send more urls?

Comment: I can change that form, if needed. Currently the code can only handle one url at the time, so that's why it's like that. But then again, I can't create x amount of input urls cause i don't know how much ill receive. also, I want to be able to input them all together, let's say like that: "example.com, example.com, example.com" etc if possible